# Unable to convert mondrian 4 schema file to mondrain 3.x schema file

Tags: schema, pentaho, mondrian

1. We have Mondrian 4 schema file (Cube file .xml) , which is created in Mondrian 4, but the Mondrian Schema workbench(It is a beta version) currently not available. Now we are using stable version of Mondrian Schema Workbench (3.6.1) so we want to read and modify the Mondrian 4 schema file in Mondrian Schema Workbench (3.6.1) .
   We use IvySE plugin but unable to succeed.
2. Is there any way to downgrade the schema file version (i.e. Mondrian 4.0 to Mondrian 3.6.1)?
3. Is any adaptor/plugin to convert schema file  (i.e. Mondrian 4.0 to Mondrian 3.6.1) ?

What we have :

1. Mondrian 4 schema file.(Cube file .xml)
2. Mondrian 3.6.1 Pentaho Schema Workbench (PSW)

Example Code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Schema name="sales" metamodelVersion="4.0">
    <PhysicalSchema>
        <Table name="sales" />
    </PhysicalSchema>
    <Cube name="Sales">
        <Dimensions>
            <Dimension name="City" key="City">
                <Attributes>
                    <Attribute name="City" keyColumn="city" hasHierarchy="false" />
                </Attributes>
                <Hierarchies>
                    <Hierarchy name="City" hasAll="true">
                        <Level attribute="City" />
                    </Hierarchy>
                </Hierarchies>
            </Dimension>
            <Dimension name="Store" key="Store">
                <Attributes>
                    <Attribute name="Store" keyColumn="store" hasHierarchy="false" />
                </Attributes>
                <Hierarchies>
                    <Hierarchy name="Store" hasAll="true">
                        <Level attribute="Store" />
                    </Hierarchy>
                </Hierarchies>
            </Dimension>
        </Dimensions>
        <MeasureGroups>
            <MeasureGroup name="Sales" table="sales">
                <Measures>
                    <Measure name="Units sold" column="unitssold" aggregator="sum" formatString="#,###" />
                </Measures>
                <DimensionLinks>
                    <ForeignKeyLink dimension="City" foreignKeyColumn="city" />
                    <ForeignKeyLink dimension="Store" foreignKeyColumn="store" />
                </DimensionLinks>
            </MeasureGroup>
        </MeasureGroups>
    </Cube>
</Schema>
```

Thanks and Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The way to downgrade 4.0 to 3.6 is edit xml manually to be compliant with 3.6.

Schema workbench had dropped support in ~2014 as far as I remember.

It don't know any tool and I don't expect somebody will spent time on creation a tool to convert from newer versions to older versions.

It depends on real xml schema you have, in very simple case if you don't use any 4.0 xml features try to edit metamodel version here:

```
<Schema name="sales" metamodelVersion="4.0">
```

Otherwise - it depends, and you can try to rewrite structure manually.